# How to filter nearby lat lng to the specific lat lng in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have an array of lat lng of different users. I want to filter only the lat lng which are around 5 kms to the specific user's lat lng. In other words nearby users around a specific user just like snapchat and facebook nearby feature. I'm using react-native-maps for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib) library which has few handy methods for you like `getDistance` based on 2 coords.

Code would be something similar to the following:

```js
const nearbyUsers = users
  .map(user => getDistance(coords, user.location.coords)
  .filter(distance => distance > 5000)
```

Comment: Its only returning the calculated distance array. I want to have data of the nearby users.

Comment: Okay so I successfully managed to implement the logic.

Comment: Added a distance key in the response data and called the getDistance() method from geolib to calculate distance from current user location to the location objects in the response.

Comment: const structuredData = resData.result.map((user) => {
      return {
        ...user,
        location: { latitude: user.location.lat, longitude: user.location.lng },
        distance: getDistance(currentLocation, {
          latitude: user.location.lat,
          longitude: user.location.lng,
        }),
      };
    });

Comment: then simply filter the data having distance less than 5 kms                                             const filterByDistance = filteredStructureData.filter(
      (data) => data.distance < 5000
    );

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a radius around you current location. Something like this:

```
const mapRadarPlusLat = yourLat - (-0.250); 
const mapRadarMinusLat = yourLat - 0.250;
const mapRadarPlusLng = yourLng - (-0.250);
const mapRadarMinusLng = yourLng - 0.250;
// With 0.250 value you make 50km radius. Im not sure what value is for 5 km.
```

Then if the user cords are inside your radius do your things.

```
if (usersLat >= mapRadarMinusLat && usersLat <= mapRadarPlusLat && usersLng<= mapRadarPlusLng && usersLng >= mapRadarMinusLng){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do anything when the user is in certain radius. I want to show nearby users on the map around current user.